# Storage image en Laravel

Tags: laravel, storage

Estoy intentando guardar imágenes y mostrarlas en una vista. Primero he empleado Unisharp/filemanager como agente externo para implementarlo con CKEditor, y ahora estoy probando a intentar subir imágenes y mostrarlas en posts de manera simple (sin CKEditor ni Filemanager de por medio.) Ante esto, me surge la siguiente pregunta.

Para guardar las imágenes, en el correspondiente controlador hago:

```
if($request->file('image')){
    $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('art_image',  $request->file('image'));
    $post->fill(['file' => asset($path)])->save();
}
```

Y guarda la imagen de manera correcta en la carpeta storage/art_imege, pero en la vista no se visualiza la imagen correctamente, y aparece con la siguiente ruta:

```
www.miapplaravel/media/art_image/WyCFOOFD.png
```

El enlace correcto debería ser

```
www.miapplaravel/**storage**/media/art_image/WyCFOOFD.png
```

¿Cómo apuntar a esa ruta?

He hecho lo siguiente:

```
if($request->file('image')){
            $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('art_image',  $request->file('image'));
            $post->fill(['file' => asset('storage/media/'.$path)])->save();
        }
```

Y en este caso sí se guardan en la carpeta correcta. Y se visualizan.

```
www.miapplaravel/storage/media/art_image/WyCFOOFD.png
```

¿Es correcto hacerlo de esta forma? No sé si es la forma correcta para acceder a storage y/o implica consideraciones por temas de seguridad de la carpeta storage.

Si alguien tiene consejo o sugerencia se lo agradecería, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener un enlace simbolico a la carpeta storage, desde public no puedes acceder, unicamente debes crear este enlace con este comando

```
php artisan storage:link
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem
En caso de que quieras puedes tambien crear otro disco en el fylesystem.php dentro de la carpeta config apuntando al directorio public

```
'nuevo_disco' => [
'driver' => 'local',
'root' => public_path(),
'visibility' => 'public'],
```

Comment: Hola @Nicolas el link en public_html es lo primero que hago. Sin eso no tendría acceso a Storage desde public. Y lo del nuevo disco también lo había probado pero, no estoy seguro de si empleé public_path como raíz. Voy a ello, y comento el resultado. ¿La forma que propongo no es recomendable no?

Comment: Hola, ya entendi, pues lo que puedes hacer es cambiar el disco por defecto en tu .env para que no tengas que anteponer prefijo storage o crear un mutador en la propiedad file con el helper url::storage, en cuanto a seguridad por convencion las imagenes de tu proyecto las puedes guardar en el path public pero documentos como pdf, imagenes de documentos si es mejor guardarlos en storage